# How do I get data from the query string in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I am working on a project for an IT class where I need to pass in a value on the query string in a php page and read it into a hidden field on an ASP page.

I currently am passing the parameter fine from the php page to ASP, but I am pretty new to .NET in general. How do I get the data out of the string and into a variable in C#? For example, if the url is **`blah.com/upload?username=washington`**, how would I get "washington" and save it into a hidden field? Thanks a ton.

Jergason

Edit

I knew it would be easy. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Do you *really* want to use a hidden field, or just store the result as a local (or perhaps class-level) variable?

Comment: Ok, seems that line was all you needed... Glad to help.

Comment: Yeah, it is a requirement for the class. Dunno why that would be better than storing it in a variable, but oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a hidden field in your aspx file:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="username" runat="server" />
```

And in your code behind populate it from the request parameter:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        username.Value = Request["username"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, now another question. What is the difference between <code>Request["username"]</code> and <code>Request.QueryString["username"]</code>?

Comment: Request["username"] looks in both QueryString and Form parameters (GET and POST).

Answer (score 13):

It seems you just want:

```
string username = Request.QueryString["username"];
```

Answer (score 3):

This returns value from **form** elements :

```
string username = Request.Form["username"];
```

This returns value from **querystring** :

```
string username = Request.QueryString["username"];
```

This looks **both** form and querystring collections :

```
string username = Request["username"];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if session ("blnIsuSERGOOD") = False or  is null (session ("blnISuSERGoo")) = True then
Response.Redirect.Querystring("name")
```

Comment: Some explanation could be useful.