# Dealing with optional parameters in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables

I've got a page in my Intranet app where sometimes there's a variable attached and sometimes there isn't.  For instance, in my pagination code, I've got this:

```
MenuItem itemMessage = NavMenu.FindItem("First");
itemMessage.NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=1&sid=6";
```

and for other sections I have this:

```
MenuItem itemMessage = NavMenu.FindItem("First");
itemMessage.NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=1";
```

Sometimes `sid` is passed to the page, and sometimes it's not.

The problem is, on the other end, I'm trying to read the values like this:

```
var queryStrings = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString.ToString());
var arrQueryStrings = queryStrings.Split('&');
var part1 = arrQueryStrings[0];
var part2 = arrQueryStrings[1];
```

If `sid` isn't passed, I get an error for part2 because it's outside the scope of the array.

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Look at the second answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646365/how-do-i-get-data-from-the-query-string-in-asp

Comment: That guy is just pulling back one variable.  I need to pull back two if there are two, and one if there is one.  I'm thinking I could check querystrings to see if "&" exists, because that's how I'll know if there are two variables or just one.  But I have no idea how to do that in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the query string object to request specific items instead of manually parsing the string.

```
string part1 = Request.QueryString["page"];
string part2 = Request.QueryString["sid"];

if(part2 != null)
{//check if part2 is sent
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I had a feeling there was an easier way.

Comment: If you're going to convert `sid` to an integer I would use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(part2)` instead of just a null check.